# MariaDB 10.1.x Online DDL spaming error log files

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Since our upgrade to a new mariadb/mysql version (previously the 10.0.x branch) we have tons of this messages in our error log. All of them are a type [note] messages but i cannot find any configuration option to disable this messages.
The log files are full of that and more important messages will be overlooked because of that.
I wonder why there is no simple option to disable all type of [note] messages.
For warnings there is a "log_warnings" flag, but there is nothing for this kind of logs. Any ideas? (We are on windows)

I've already tried the `log_warnings=1` and `log_warnings=2`. Both don't hide the note messages. I don't want to just show errors only with `log_warnings=0`, warnings are sometimes good to know.

```
2016-02-05  5:13:33 5396 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start
2016-02-05  5:13:33 5396 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start reading clustered index of the table and create temporary files
2016-02-05  5:13:33 5396 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : End of reading clustered index of the table and create temporary files
2016-02-05  5:13:33 5396 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start merge-sorting index `PRIMARY` (1 / 3), estimated cost : 10.0000
2016-02-05  5:13:33 5396 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : End of  merge-sorting index `PRIMARY` (1 / 3)
2016-02-05  5:13:33 5396 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start building index `PRIMARY` (1 / 3), estimated cost : 15.0000
2016-02-05  5:13:33 5396 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : End of building index `PRIMARY` (1 / 3)
2016-02-05  5:13:33 5396 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Completed
```

Comment: after modify the logging level, did you restart the service?

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin Yes. I also always double check the `SHOW VARIABLES`. Anyway, the default is `log_warnings=1` when you do not change this setting, which should even not show the notice failure.

Comment: are the DDL entries not like a transaction log? - i.e. a requirement that you can't get away from once enabled

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin Those log messages appear in the error-log (or syslog, whatever you've enabled), not in the separate transaction log.

Comment: Goog to know MariaDB has a built-in syslog support, opposite to the rest of MySQL server family. And the question is whether syslog-directed messages has the syslog levels set properly. I don't have a MariaDB installation to check it, but this could make a workaround easy.